# jQuery delay not working on mouseout

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, delay

Can someone explain why this won't work?

```
jQuery('.right-et-tooltip').delay(800).mouseout(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.right-et-tooltip-box').animate({ opacity: 'hide', left: '-100px' }, 30);
});
```

I get no delay at all. Just as soon as the mouse is out, BOOM it goes away.

Thanks, I have tried a few things, so just frustrated.

Comment: Can you provide the html as well. I'd suggest you toss it up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Oh, but couldn't get it work at all there...missing something..not sure what though

Comment: You made a simple mistake by binding the `delay()` to the jQuery selector instead of the `mouseout` function.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delay is doing absolutely nothing because it's bound to the jQuery selector and not to the function within the `mouseout` handler.

Try this instead...

```
jQuery('.right-et-tooltip').mouseout(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.right-et-tooltip-box').delay(800).animate({ opacity: 'hide', left: '-100px' }, 30);
});
```

Your jsFiddle with the correction applied...

http://jsfiddle.net/zGtBN/2/

---

**EDIT (a side note):**

It would be much better to use the `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` methods rather than the `mouseover` & `mouseout` methods which tend to cause a rapid blinking effect during the time your mouse is hovering.

[Then you can simply combine the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers into one by using the jQuery `.hover()` method.](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Your same exact two functions insterted into a `.hover()` method here...

http://jsfiddle.net/zGtBN/3/

---

**EDIT 2:**

When you re-enter before the leave animation completes, the animations will queue up.  If you enter & leave really fast several times, you'll have all those animations to blink on/off before they stop.

To prevent the animation queue from stacking up and creating a new issue where it comes on/off because of the `mouseleave` delay, [use a jQuery `.stop(true, false)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the `mouseenter` function like this...

```
jQuery(this).find('.right-et-tooltip-box').stop(true,false).animate({ opacity: 'show', left: '-100px' }, 30);
```

Upon `mouseenter`, it stops any `mouseleave` animation immediately.  The `true` on the "clearQueue" option clears out the animation queue and the `false` on the "jumpToEnd" option says to stop the current animation instead of completing it immediately.

Modified demo...

http://jsfiddle.net/zGtBN/4/

Comment: WOrked great, and I made that change to mouseenter and mouseleave, it still blinks but it comes back...i'm sure I'll find a way to make it not do that. It does it because I do 'leave' and so it starts that delay on blinking off then shows back up.

Comment: @oneadvent: that's a different issue. It's because the animation is queueing when you enter & leave before the animation can complete. Use jQuery's `.stop()` method to stop the animation and clear the queue.  See my latest edit for the demo.